# Errors when uploading msix packaged app on Microsoft Developer Account

Tags: powershell, self-signed-certificate, msix

[Errors that occur when I try to upload my msix file to the Microsoft Developers Account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQfa1.png)

I am not sure how to fix these errors and would appreciate some help. I used the MSIX Packaging Tool and I created a self-signed certificate using powershell. Maybe there some discrepancies between the information I put on my app and the information I put on the packaging tool. I used Gdevelop to develop the app if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, share your code and actual error, rather than image

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list with common errors that you can see when trying to publish your app to the store, among which are yours too.

- [MSIX FAQ - store publishing errors](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-msix.html#question182)